# New popup does not point to javascript links and libraries

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I use this function to open a new window using the htmlMarkup as html content.

```
function PC_DownloadAsPdfSuccess(htmlMarkup) {
        $("div#rightcolumnFARP").detachLoader();
        if (htmlMarkup != null && htmlMarkup.length != 0) {               
            var printWindow = window.open("", "");
            var newDocument = printWindow.document;

            newDocument.open();
            newDocument.write(htmlMarkup);
            newDocument.close();
        } 
    }
```

The new page is working as expected, except that is does not recognise the include js libraries, such as jquery, MicrosoftMvcAjax.js, etc. I get all sorts of error like:

$ is not defined, jquery is not defined, xVal is not defined. I'm pretty sure it's because the path for the links in the new window do not point correctly to the scripts, but only in IE. Firefox does not have this issue.

Here is the head htmlMarkup that seems to be the problem. I've tried playing with the path by going up several levels (using ../) but still no luck.

```
    <head id="Head1"><title>
    Print preview
</title>

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.6.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <link href="/Content/ui.base.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
        media="screen" />

<script src="/Scripts/utils.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcValidation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.6.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.1.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.preloadImages.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/grid.base.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/grid.formedit.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.tablednd_0_5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/xVal.jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-html-encode-decode.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-timedLogout.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/round-corners.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/superfish.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.formatCurrency-1.3.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.tipTip.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/easyslider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.json.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/browserSelector.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.antiForgeryToken.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="/Scripts/jquery.watermark.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="/Scripts/jquery.autocomplete.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
       <script src="/Scripts/jquery.calculation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/DetectBrowser.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.infoblock.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.jloader.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jqGridHeight.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.alerts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/tabs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/CustomValidation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/fullcalendar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jqplot/jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.pieRenderer.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.barRenderer.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.barRenderer.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.canvasAxisTickRenderer.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.canvasTextRenderer.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.highlighter.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jqplot/excanvas.min.js"></script>
<head>
```

Comment: Good grief, that's **alot** of JavaScript.

Comment: What version(s) of IE are you experiencing this issue in?

Answer (score 0):

This is because u have already opened the window, which would have finished the loading event, after that u are placing the content, so the content is treated as text and the script functions are not loaded to your window you have opened. If suppose if have the javascript functions written openly on the window within script tag it would have worked, since the external script files are not got loaded, u are getting those errors, try some other way to fix ur problem

Comment: Maybe so. But why is only Internet Explorer doing this? Firefox loads the      javascript just fine

Comment: That I don't why this weird thing happens in IE

Comment: @ArmGates Except, by your definition, the abnormal thing is happening in Firefox, not IE.

Comment: If @ArmGates is correct, you can just take the "script" blocks out of the head, and put them into body -- but I don't think that's really your problem; since your basically saying that cross site JSON queries won't ever work in IE.